# USB type-c Spec Analysis

Tags: usb, usb-c

I'm having difficulties anlysing the [USB Type-C Spec R2](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf), section *4.6.2.1 "USB Type-C Current"* paragraph. It is said that "When a Source is advertising USB Type-C Default current, the Sink behavior is defined as follows: [...] It attaches as a USB Type-C Power Sinking Device (PSD), after which the Sink may draw up to 500 mA. ". I'm not sure if the USB Type-C default current advertised is referring to the USB 2.0/3.x:0.5/0.9A (which I think is the case given the previous paragraph) or the 1.5/3A usb type-c current.

The former interpretation would be a violation of the USB 2.0/3.x, since you can't draw more than 100mA without enumeration. The latter would mean that every website saying you only need to monitor the CC lines to draw up to 0.1/1.5/3A depending on the state of CC is wrong, and I would also not understand the whole point of the CC current advertisement.

Given the use of "default" in the previous and next paragraphs I believe it's the former interpretation. Am I wrong to believe there's a violation?

Answer (score 1):

Type-C specifications define not only "USB devices" but also PSD - Power Sinking Devices. These are devices that don't have USB functionality, nor alternate mode functionality. The specs even has an explicit example - USB light (see P.27). Obviously the USB specifications do not apply to PSDs, and they cannot follow the limit of non-enumerated USB devices.

Therefore, there is no contradiction nor violation of anything.

Comment: Allow me to expand on that.  There's 3 data paths inside USB-C that can all act independently.  There's USB 2.0, the 4 "superspeed" lanes, and USB-PD.  There's 3 means to manage power transfer, USB 2.0/3.x, USB-BC, and USB-PD.  USB-C devices may use more than 1 to negotiate power.  As they all start in the same place of the host sourcing 5 V the host can support any 1, 2, or all 3.  These 3 data paths and 3 power protocols are not completely independent, only 1 power protocol can be active at once.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  So you're saying it's not a violation, because it's not a USB device but a PSD ? So for example a PSD can draw 0.5A on an old computer usb 2.0 port ? That also means that a PSD can draw 0.5A in any case without checking CC lines since it can draw 0.5A for legacy 2.0/3.x ports and 1.5A/3A on true usb-c ports depending on CC state.